# Show / Hide and Slide Table

Tags: jquery

I have a table where in one of the rows I have a child table.
When the anchor with class "Show" is clicked I would like to:

1. Make the child table visible ... Sliding it.
2. Change the anchor class from "Show" to "Hide".

How can I do this?

My code is as follows:

```
<table class="Parent">
  <tr>
      <td class="Task"></td>
      <td>Row1</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Task"><a class="Show">Show</a></td>
    <td>Row 2
      <table class="Child" style="display: none">
          <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Row2</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Thank You!

Comment: check out `slideToggle()` or `hide()` and `show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap the `.Child` in a div, or else it displays it as a `table-cell` which will affect the slide animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Show, .Hide').click(function(){
        var child = $(this).closest('tr').find('.Child').closest('div');

        if($(this).hasClass('Show')){
            $(this).removeClass('Show').addClass('Hide').html('Hide');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('Hide').addClass('Show').html('Show');
        }

        child.slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

DEMO (WITH DIV):
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/ppgH9/9/

DEMO (Without DIV):
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/ppgH9/8/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this?

**See Demo:**

i have used `toggle()`

http://jsfiddle.net/KcRTm/3/